# @XmlElementWrapper for web method using JAX-WS

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws

I have a web service like below, it contains a web method which will return a list of objects:

```
@WebService(name = "ClubMembershipPortType", serviceName = "ClubMembershipService", portName = "ClubMembershipSoapPort", targetNamespace = "http://club.com/api/ws")
public class ClubMembershipWS {
  @WebMethod(operationName = "findClubMembershipsByClubId", action = "urn:findClubMembershipsByClubId")
  @WebResult(name = "club_membership")
  public List<ClubMembership> findClubMembershipsByClubId(@XmlElement(required=true)
                                                        @WebParam(name = "club_id") String clubId, 
                                                        @WebParam(name = "status") StatusEnum status)
  ...
  ...
  }
}
```

The response I got for the api request is like below:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:findClubMembersByClubIdResponse xmlns:ns2="http://club.com/api/ws">
         <club_membership>
            ...
         </club_membership>
         <club_membership>
            ...
         </club_membership>
      </ns2:findClubMembersByClubIdResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The question is how to use `@XmlElementWrapper` (or other way?) to make the response like below?

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:findClubMembersByClubIdResponse xmlns:ns2="http://club.com/api/ws">
         <club_membership_list>
             <club_membership>
               ...
            </club_membership>
            <club_membership>
               ...
            </club_membership>
         </club_membership_list>
      </ns2:findClubMembersByClubIdResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: by the way, i saw some related post [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-570)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="club_membership_list", required=true)  
@XmlElement(name="club_membership", required=true) 
public List<ClubMembership> findClubMembershipsByClubId(@WebParam(name = "club_id") String clubId, 
@WebParam(name = "status") StatusEnum status)
```

Comment: This solution actually worked for me in my issue I had here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095911/jax-ws-place-a-wrapper-around-an-arraylist-being-returned

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your method with:

```
@WebResult(name="club_membership_list", targetNamespace = "http://club.com/api/ws")
```