# JAX-WS: Place a wrapper around an ArrayList being returned

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have the following endpoint interface:

```
@WebService
public interface SEIWebService {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="CreateWorkOrderItemResponse")
    CreateWorkOrderItemResponse createWorkItem(@WebParam(name = "CreateWorkOrderItemRequest")CreateWorkOrderItemRequest request);
}
```

The implementation:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.someCompany.SEIWebService", portName = "SEIWebServices")
public class SEIWebServiceImpl implements SEIWebService{

    @Override
    public CreateWorkOrderItemResponse createWorkItem(CreateWorkOrderItemRequest request) {
        CreateWorkOrderItemResponse response = new CreateWorkOrderItemResponse();
        response.setResponseCode("Testing Create 2222");
        response.addError("Error 1");
        response.addError("Error 2");

        return response;
    }
```

And lastly, the code for the response object

```
public class CreateWorkOrderItemResponse {
    private String responseCode = null;
    private ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public String getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void addError(String error) {
        errorList.add(error);
    }

    public void setErrorList(ArrayList<String> errorList) {
        this.errorList = errorList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getErrorList() {
        return errorList;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the response back in SoapUI comes out like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:createWorkItemResponse xmlns:ns2="http://someCompany.com/">
         <CreateWorkOrderItemResponse>
            <errorList>Error 1</errorList>
            <errorList>Error 2</errorList>
            <responseCode>Testing Create 2222</responseCode>
            <testList/>
         </CreateWorkOrderItemResponse>
      </ns2:createWorkItemResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Finally, **the question**... With the code above, is there a way to change it so I can add a "wrapper" around the errorList responses? I am looking to have the SOAP message response look like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:createWorkItemResponse xmlns:ns2="http://someCompany.com/">
         <CreateWorkOrderItemResponse>
            <Errors>
                <errorList>Error 1</errorList>
                <errorList>Error 2</errorList>
            </Errors>
            <responseCode>Testing Create 2222</responseCode>
            <testList/>
         </CreateWorkOrderItemResponse>
      </ns2:createWorkItemResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I will, of course, be changing "errorList" variable name to something else.

Comment: Oh, and `testList` was just me trying something out. That can be ignored.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I had to use the `XmlElementWrapper` annotation for this. So the code is now:

```
public class CreateWorkOrderItemResponse {
    private String responseCode = null;
    private ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public String getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void addError(String error) {
        errorList.add(error);
    }

    public void setErrorList(ArrayList<String> errorList) {
        this.errorList = errorList;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="error_list") 
    @XmlElement(name="error")
    public ArrayList<String> getErrorList() {
        return errorList;
    }
}
```